# Get multiple result using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this regex expression

```
let paragraph = "112-39-8552 asdasdas 123-58-3695";
let result = paragraph.match(/(\d{3}\-\d{2}-\d{4})+/);
console.log(result);
```

I will have this as a result

```
[
  '112-39-8552',
  '112-39-8552',
  index: 0,
  input: '112-39-8552 asdasdas 123-58-3695',
  groups: undefined
]
```

It only find the first pattern but not the second

how can I include `123-58-3695` in the search result?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `g` flag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global

```
let result = paragraph.match(/(\d{3}\-\d{2}-\d{4})+/g);
```

> The value of global is a Boolean and true if the "g" flag was used; otherwise, false. The "g" flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested against all possible matches in a string. A regular expression defined as both global ("g") and sticky ("y") will ignore the global flag and perform sticky matches.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the "g" flag to the regex like:

```js
let paragraph = "112-39-8552 asdasdas 123-58-3695";
let result = paragraph.match(/(\d{3}\-\d{2}-\d{4})+/g);
console.log(result);
```

The `g` is for [global search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global). Meaning it'll match all occurrences. Without the `g` flag, it'll only test for the first match.